# Which type of Tree Data Structure is suitable for efficient frequent pattern mining?

Tags: data-structures, information-retrieval, trie

I am currently working on frequent pattern mining(FPM). I was googling about the data structures which can be used for FPM. My main concern is space-compactness of the data structures as am planning to use distributed algorithm over it (handling synchronization over a DS that fits in my main memory). The list of data structures i have come across are,

- Prefix-Tree
- Compact Prefix-Tree or Radix Tree
- Prefix Hash Tree (PHT)
- Burst Tree (currently reading how it works)

I dunno the order in which each data structure evolved. Can anyone tell me which DS (not limited to the DS mentioned above) is the best Data Structure that fits my requirements ?

P.S: currently am considering burst tree is the best known space-efficient data structure for FPM.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. The data structure you use probably isn't as important as the algorithm you select. The canonical example is the Apriori algorithm, but if the data fits in memory there are other alternatives (Eclat and FP-Growth). It's impossible to recommend a data structure, though, without understanding the nature of your data. And your intent to synchronize access is going to affect that decision, too. Are you asking how to represent the data you're mining, or how to represent the intermediate results?

Comment: @JimMischel  : Not that sir. Every algorithm including MOMENT, IncMine, FP-Growth, APstream, etc have some steps in common. Only factor that decides their performance is the use of efficient data structure. One simple example is the evolution of Closed Enumeration Tree (CET) out of Prefix tree, becaz of the reason that Prefix tree won't fit in memory. Here the algorithm is not a big concern. How we store the intermediate results is important, there comes the effect of data structures. Thats why am bothering about data-structures than algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the question is broad. However, if you're looking for a space-efficient prefix tree, then I would strongly recommend a [Burst Trie](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~jz/fulltext/acmtois02.pdf). I wrote an implementation and was able to squeeze a lot of space efficiency out of it for Stripe's latest Capture the Flag. (They had a problem which used 4 nodes at less than 500mb each that "required" a suffix tree.)

If you're looking for an implementation of an efficient burst trie then check mine out.

https://github.com/nbauernfeind/scala-burst-trie